# Specialized Singleton implementation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, typescript

I am looking for specialized singleton implementation, probably I might be using wrong terminology  and hence looking for expert suggestion. Here is my scenario:

There is common code which can be called by ComponentA or ComponentB. I need to push telemetry data from the common code. Telemetry needs to have information that whether this common code get called by ComponentA or ComponentB.

So common code will have just this line of code:

**telemetry.pushData(this._area, data);**

where this._area tells the telemetry data is getting pushed for which component

I need to push telemetry data from multiple places so it would be good if object got created once and used through out the code lifetime

One option I can think of passing component context to the common code which in mind doesn't look right, hence looking for suggestion what kind of pattern one should use in this case?

This is what I am thinking

```
// Telemetry.ts file present in shared code

export class Telemetry extends Singleton {
public constructor() {
    super();
}

public static instance(): Telemetry {
    return super.instance<Telemetry>(Telemetry);
}

public publishEvent(data): void {
    if (!this.area) {
        throw new Error("Error: Initialize telemetry class with right area");
    }

    pushtelemetryData(this.area, data);
}

public area: string;
}



// Create Telemetry object from component A
Telemetry.instance().area = "ComponentA";

// Shared code will call telemetry publishEvent
Telemetry.instance().publishEvent(data);
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to call `telemetry.pushData(data)` from different components, or is it that other way around?

Comment: this needs to be called from common code...ComponentA called common code and common code needs to push telemetry data

Comment: What's `Singleton`? What does `super.instance<Telemetry>(Telemetry)` do? Why would you want to assign the `area` like that? Is that something you'll do before each call to `publishEvent`? Why not just passing `"ComponentA"` as a parameter to the function as I showed in my answer?

Comment: Singleton is class to create singleton object, assignment of area will happen once from the component class, no need to do before each call. Say I have two webpage, page1 and page2. Both page have some code, this common code sending telemetry data. So I am looking for telemetry object per page context. While sending telemetry data I need to pass information which tells common code running under which page context. With your code I didn't understand how I can do that, maybe I am missing something here. Sorry for the confusion and thanks alot for your patience.

Comment: with my approach I am creating singleton telemetry object in the page initialization so that it will be same through out the same page context as soon as user change the page everything will be destroyed and new telemetry object will get created with that page context.

Comment: How are you loading the scripts in your web pages? Are you using a module system (import/require/etc) or do you just have script tags in your html?

Comment: I am using module system

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good pattern to use in TypeScript where you would generally inject dependencies.

If you must absolutely do it then you can do it by faking it somewhat:

```
namespace Telemetry {
    var instance : SingletonSomething;

    export function push(data: Any) : void {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonSomething();
        }
        instance.push(data);
    }

    class SingletonSomething() { ... }
}
```

and then you could call

```
Telemetry.push(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Roy but how we'll know that which component called the Telemetry.push(data); I thought to have some variable in SingletonSomething class which will initialized from each component to pass the component information while pushing telemetry data

Answer (score 0):

You can imitate the singleton pattern in typescript easily:

```
class Telemetry {
    private static instance: Telemetry;

    public static getInstance(): Telemetry {
        if (Telemetry.instance == null) {
            Telemetry.instance = new Telemetry();
        }

        return Telemetry.instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you have your code in some sort of closure (module, namespace, etc) then you can replace the static member with:

```
let telemetryInstance: Telemetry;
export class Telemetry {
    public static getInstance(): Telemetry {
        if (telemetryInstance == null) {
            telemetryInstance = new Telemetry();
        }

        return telemetryInstance;
    }
    ...
}
```

But then you can also replace the static method with:

```
let telemetryInstance: Telemetry;
export function getTelemetryInstance(): Telemetry {
    if (telemetryInstance == null) {
        telemetryInstance = new Telemetry();
    }

    return telemetryInstance;
}

export class Telemetry {
    ...
}
```

At this point, in case you are using some sort of closure, you might ask yourself if you really need the class at all?
If you use this as a module:

```
// telemetry.ts
export interface TelemetryData {
    ...
}

export function pushData(data: TelemetryData): void {
    ...
}
```

Then you get exactly what you're looking for, and this is more of the "javascript way" of doing it.

---

#### Edit

In the telemetry module there's no need to know the users of it.
If the `Telemetry.pushData` function needs to have information about the object that called it then define an interface for it:

```
// telemetry.ts
export interface TelemetryData {
    ...
}

export interface TelemetryComponent {
    name: string;
    ...
}

export function pushData(data: TelemetryData, component: TelemetryComponent): void {
    ...
}
```

Then in the other modules, where you use it:

```
// someModule.ts
import * as Telemetry from "./telemetry";

class MyComponent implement Telemetry.TelemetryComponent {
    // can also be a simple string property
    public get name() {
        return "MyComponent";
    }

    fn() {
        ...
        Telemetry.pushData({ ... }, this);
    }
}
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

Because you are using a module system, your module files are enough to make singletons, there's no need for a class to achieve that.
You can do this:

```
// telemetry.ts
let area: string;

export interface TelemetryData {
    ...
}

export function setArea(usedArea: string) {
    area = usedArea;
}

export function pushData(data: TelemetryData): void {
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
Telemetry.setArea("ComponentA");
...
Telemetry.publishEvent(data);
```

The telemetry module will be created only once per page, so you can treat the entire module as a singleton.
Export only the functions that are needed.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i missed to explain my question properly. One of the requirement what i am looking for is that I need to know which component pushing telemetry data. Say same code is called by ComponentA and ComponentB at two different point of time then how can i differentiate who called at what time?

Comment: Can't you pass the instance of the component to the `pushData` function? Something like: `pushData(date: TelemetryData, component: Component) { ... }`

Comment: the common code is not small, it contains around 20 ts files and each file will push telemetry data, with this i need to pass component context across files. Maybe I can put component information in some common place which I can initialize through component in the beginning before calling common code. Here I am not sure what is the correct pattern to initialize this information before calling common code.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, maybe I am still missing how i'll know the component information from the shared code, I edited my question with some piece of code what I am thinking